# How to call a method with a parameter decorated with @Vaule annotation in a spring project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

When there is a parameter decorated with @Value annotaion in a method, it is ofcourse no compile error. Just like the code bellow:

```
public void Sample0(@Value("${hmac.key}") Optional<String> key) {
   if (key.isPresent()) {
         System.out.println(key.get());
    } else {
          System.out.println("can not find key");
    }
 }
```

My Question is how to call a function like this? I try to call it directory, but it failed. The calling function code bellow.

```
@Test
public void sampleTest0() {
     JwtService.Sample0();
}
```

So anyone can tell me what's the right way to call the function? Thx.

Comment: what are you trying achieve?

Comment: @Deadpool I just want to test the varied usages of the Value annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think another way of doing this is to save `@Value` as local variable and then use it into function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `@Value` in parameters only in constructors. Your `Sample0` is not a constructor, just a regular method because it has a return type, i.e. `void`.

If you use `@Value` in constructor parameter, you can autowire `Sample0` and spring will inject the value while instantiating it.

If you need to pass a value to a regular method instead, you can use `@Value` on a field in the calling class and then pass that field as an argument to this method in `Sample0`.